# How to configure Jetty to use HTTPS in Microsoft Azure VM?

Tags: azure, https, jetty, virtual-machine

We have a Microsoft VM in which we have an SQL Server and a Jetty for Geoserver.

So far the setting for HTTP is working perfectly.

Now they go for HTTPS. From my understanding, they just 'pay more to choose the option' for HTTPS (there is no physical file 'certificate'?)

The HTTPS access for SQL Server is working. However, the problem is the HTTPS for the Geoserver, precisely the Jetty.

I did some search. But I am still confused. Is there a quick approach on this?

Error Thrown:

net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR

Comment: this has nothing to do with azure, azure doesn't affect how applications work on your vm

Comment: @4c74356b41 Does that mean that, I have to use some kind of certificate for the Jetty in the VM? The reason asking this, since we paid for the HTTPS of the VM, can we re-use that on the VM?

Comment: what does `we paid for https of the vm` mean? azure doesn't bill for using port 443

Comment: hm... so you mean that (certificate) is bought separately? (if so, can it be re-use for the jetty?)

Comment: well, I'm not sure if you bought it separately, I think azure sells certificates, but for webapps, I haven't seen a way to buy a certificate for a VM, but anyway, you can reuse the cert, most likely. I'm not that good with the certificate stuff, if you can import it into jetty - you can use it

Comment: Thanks for your info. I would communicate with the colleague to validate this.

Comment: Apparently, they are buying SSL from Godaddy. Now i have to look into how that SSL be applied in Jetty instead of IIS.

Comment: @4c74356b41 Are you aware that this could be hacked by having a reverse proxy url at the Azure?  Reference: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/156540/installing-geoserver-on-https-in-iis7
No sure if it is a work-able workaround.